# Aggregation of dataframe by lookup in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes like below.

`dfu` is sort of a look up table for probability of presence of properties per `id` based on past studies - stored as `prop1`, `prop2` and so on.
`dfi` contains a bunch of ids found in an experiment - not all ids in `dfu` may be present and one or more ids not present in `dfu` may be present in `dfi`

```
> set.seed(100)
> dfu <- data.frame(id=rep(1:6,1, replace = FALSE), prop1=sample(0:10 / 10,6, replace=TRUE), prop2=sample(0:10 / 10,6 , replace = TRUE) )
> dfu
  id prop1 prop2
1  1   0.8   0.3
2  2   0.4   0.4
3  3   0.6   0.8
4  4   0.1   0.7
5  5   0.6   0.2
6  6   0.9   0.3
> dfi <- data.frame(id = c(sample(1:3, 6, replace = TRUE),7))
> dfi
  id
1  2
2  3
3  2
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  7
```

With `dfu`, given `dfi` I need to compute the presence per property for the whole population of ids in `dfi` on a per property basis. This could be done by counting the number of occurrences per `id` in `dfi` and then take a weighted average per property. The ids not present in `dfu` may be excluded from the weighted average as no presence per property values are available for them.

So for `prop1` it would be like `(0.8*1 + 0.4*3 + 0.6*2)/(1 + 3 + 2) = 0.53` - 1,3,2 used here are occurrences of ids 1, 2 & 3 respectively in `dfi`.

The output would be like below

```
prop1   prop2
0.5333     0.5167
```

prefer base R approach, other approaches welcome. The number of columns could be many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use base R `apply` column - wise to calculate the weighted mean for every column in `dfu`.

```
apply(dfu[-1], 2, function(x) weighted.mean(x[match(dfi$id, dfu$id)]))

#prop1     prop2 
#0.5333333 0.5166667
```

**EDIT**

As per edit if there are cases when there are `id`'s in `dfi` which are not present in `dfu` we can use the answer with `nomatch` argument

```
apply(dfu[-1], 2, function(x) weighted.mean(x[match(dfi$id, dfu$id, nomatch = 0)]))
```

Comment: @akrun could you please tell me how? and no need to copy an "incorrect" approach.

Comment: You can check the OP's input data

Comment: What did I copy?  I have an approach using `data.table`.  `weighted.mean` is not patented to you

Comment: @RonakShah - this answer works well, when `dfi` contains only `ids` present in `dfu`. However if `dfi` contains an `id` not present in `dfu`, it gives the weighted avg. as NAs

Comment: @user3206440 Just update with `nomatch` argument. See answer.

Comment: @user3206440 just add `na.rm = TRUE` in `weighted.mean`

Comment: @RonakShah - for above case, if `dfu` were to have an additional col, say `team` with `ids` 1,2,3 having team `A` and 4,5,6 have team `B` -  instead of the weighted mean for the entire set, is there a way to get the weighted mean per col to be grouped by `team` such that `prop1`, `prop2`  is available by `A` , `B` teams ? - new question ?

Comment: @user3206440 Probably, you should ask a new question. Won't give you an answer with a small change.

Comment: @RonakShah - question here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/42242497/3206440

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dfu)`), do a join with 'dfi' `on` the 'id' column, loop through the columns mentioned in `.SDcols` and get the `weighted.mean`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfu)[dfi, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean) ,on = .(id), .SDcols = prop1:prop2]
#      prop1     prop2
#1: 0.5333333 0.5166667
```

If we have elements in 'dfi' that are not in 'dfu', use the `nomatch = 0`

```
setDT(dfu)[dfi, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean) ,on = .(id), nomatch = 0, .SDcols = prop1:prop2]
```

#### data

```
dfu <- structure(list(id = 1:6, prop1 = c(0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9
), prop2 = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3)), .Names = c("id", 
"prop1", "prop2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

dfi <- structure(list(id = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = "id", 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```