# apply distribution to new sample set

Tags: r

I have a data-frame `dfu` that holds for each `id` (id belongs to one `team`, `team` has many `ids`) the percentage samples where a bunch of properties `prop1`, `prop2` and so on are observed based on some past studies - this is used as sort of reference table for future studies. Now there is data from new experiment which gives a new set of `ids`. I need to find the percentage samples where `prop1`, `prop2` and so on are observed on per `team` basis by using the reference data in `dfu`. This could be done by counting the number of occurrences per `id` in `dfi` and then take a weighted average grouped by `team`.- not all ids in `dfu` may be present and one or more ids not present in `dfu` may be present in `dfi`. The ids not present in `dfu` may be excluded from the weighted average as no presence per property values are available for them.

```
dfu <- data.frame(id=1:6, team=c('A',"B","C","A","A","C"), prop1=c(0.8,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.8,0.9), prop2=c(0.2,0.3,.3,.2,.2,.3))
> dfu
  id team prop1 prop2
   1    A   0.8   0.2
   2    B   0.9   0.3
   3    C   0.6   0.3
   4    A   0.5   0.2
   5    A   0.8   0.2
   6    C   0.9   0.3
> 
> dfi <- data.frame(id=c(2  , 3  , 2  , 1  , 4  , 3  , 7))
> dfi
  id
   2
   3
   2
   1
   4
   3
   7
```

The output format would be like below. For example the value for `prop1` for group `A` would be `(0.8*1 + 0.5*1)/2 = 0.65`.

```
team  prop1   prop2
  A            
  B    
  C
```

prefer base R approach, other approaches welcome. The number of columns could be many.

Comment: related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/42105259/3206440, may be a more specific case of this.

Comment: I suspect that your set.seed(100) does not correspond to the data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how to do it with base R.

With data.table it's should be pretty easy.
Let convert your data.frames into data.table.

```
library(data.table)

dfu <- data.frame(id=1:6, team=c('A',"B","C","A","A","C"), prop1=c(0.8,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.8,0.9), prop2=c(0.2,0.3,.3,.2,.2,.3))

dfi <- data.frame(id=c(2  , 3  , 2  , 1  , 4  , 3  , 7))
dfi <- data.table(dfi)
dfu <- data.table(dfu)
```

Then merge them like

```
dfu[dfi,on="id"]

## > dfu[dfi,on="id"]                  
##    id team prop1 prop2
## 1:  2    B   0.9   0.3
## 2:  3    C   0.6   0.3
## 3:  2    B   0.9   0.3
## 4:  1    A   0.8   0.2
## 5:  4    A   0.5   0.2
## 6:  3    C   0.6   0.3
## 7:  7   NA    NA    NA
```

Then we just have to perform the mean by group. In fact we can to it one liner like

```
    dfu[dfi,on="id"][,mean(prop1),team]

## > dfu[dfi,on="id"][,mean(prop1),team] 
##    team   V1
## 1:    B 0.90
## 2:    C 0.60
## 3:    A 0.65
## 4:   NA   NA
```

You can achieve the same thing in base R by merging the data.frame and using the function `aggregate` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

taking cue from @DJJ's answer.

```
dfu <- data.frame(id=1:6, team=c('A',"B","C","A","A","C"),
          prop1=c(0.8,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.8,0.9), 
          prop2=c(0.2,0.3,.3,.2,.2,.3))
dfi <- data.frame(id=c(2  , 3  , 2  , 1  , 4  , 3  , 7))
```

Merge by id

```
> dfx <- merge(dfi, dfu, by="id")
> dfx
  id team prop1 prop2
1  1    A   0.8   0.2
2  2    B   0.9   0.3
3  2    B   0.9   0.3
4  3    C   0.6   0.3
5  3    C   0.6   0.3
6  4    A   0.5   0.2
```

Aggregate `prop1` and `prop2` by `team` with `mean`

```
> aggregate(cbind(prop1, prop2) ~ team, dfx, mean)
  team prop1 prop2
1    A  0.65   0.2
2    B  0.90   0.3
3    C  0.60   0.3
```